# CakePHP 2.5 complex find filtering by containable key

Tags: mysql, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have 4 tables connected to each other

Talent table

```
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created            | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| firstname          | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname           | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone_num          | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

this table will contain rows such as

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | firstname | lastname   |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | barney    | stinson    |
|  2 | Ted       | Mosby      |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

TalentCategory table

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created        | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| talent_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| talent_name_id | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active      | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

TalentName table

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created      | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name         | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| talent_count | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

this table will contain rows such as

```
+----+-------------------+-----------------+
| id | name              | slug            |
+----+-------------------+-----------------+
|  1 | actor / actress   | actor-actress   |
|  2 | dancer            | dancer          |
|  3 | model             | model           |
|  4 | singer / musician | singer-musician |
+----+-------------------+-----------------+
```

and TalentMedia table

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created      | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| talent_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| media_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_cover     | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| is_avatar    | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| like_count   | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| view_count   | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| is_published | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| is_deleted   | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| is_approved  | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| is_suspended | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Talent `hasMany` TalentCategory `belongsTo` TalentName

Talent `hasMany` TalentMedia

i am trying to achieve

```
SELECT 

Talent.id,
Talent.firstname,
Talent.lastname,
TalentCategory.id,
TalentCategory.talent_id,
TalentCategory.talent_name_id,
TalentName.name,
TalentName.id,
TalentMedia.talent_id,
TalentMedia.media_id,
TalentMedia.is_suspended,
TalentMedia.is_avatar,
TalentMedia.is_cover


FROM talents AS Talent

JOIN talent_talents AS TalentCategory ON TalentCategory.talent_id = Talent.id
JOIN talent_names AS TalentName ON TalentName.id = TalentCategory.talent_name_id
JOIN talent_medias AS TalentMedia ON TalentMedia.talent_id = Talent.id

WHERE TalentName.id = 4 AND TalentMedia.is_suspended != 1 AND TalentMedia.is_cover !=1 AND TalentMedia.is_avatar = 1
GROUP BY Talent.id
```

or

```
select all talents which is a singer/musician that avatar is not suspended
```

here's an [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8560/1/0) describing the desired output

from my controller so that i can implement it inside my paginator settings. i have been trying everything with no luck.

i try the [**custom find types**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-custom-find) or the [**custom query pagination**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) but i don't quite understand the documentation.

please help me on how to achieve this

Comment: your DB structure looks a little off. If a Talent hasMany TalentCategory then you should be fetching Talent and TalentCategory separately no?

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno uhm i dont quite understand your question, a talent can have many talent_categories (Barney stinson is an actor, a singer and a dancer), thats why i have to map it this way. i updated mine, hope it helps explaining

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide *proper* DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry the thing is, the problem is not in the sql or query, i can fetch the rows just fine, the question is actually, how can i do it in CakePHP find method? anyway i updated the question to provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working by creating a custom pagination, i don't know if this is the right approach, at least my solution works for now

First i override Cake's `paginate` and `paginateCount` method

```
public function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {
    $recursive = -1;
    $sql_query  = $this->paginateQuery; //same query as [SqlFiddle][1]

    if(!empty($conditions)){
        $sql_query .= 'WHERE ';
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $cond) {
            $cond_str[] = $key .' '. $cond;
        }
        $sql_query .=implode(" AND ", $cond_str)." ";

    }

    $sql_query .= "GROUP BY Talent.id ";
    $sql_query .= "ORDER BY Talent.id DESC ";
    $sql_query .= "LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $limit) . ', ' . $limit;

    $results = $this->query($sql_query);
    $this->virtualFields['fullname'] = 'CONCAT(Talent.firstname, " ", Talent.lastname)';
    return $results;
}

public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {
    $recursive = -1;
    $sql_query  = $this->paginateQuery; //same query as [SqlFiddle][1]

    if(!empty($conditions)){
        $sql_query .= 'WHERE ';
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $cond) {
            $cond_str[] = $key .' '. $cond;
        }
        $sql_query .=implode(" AND ", $cond_str)." ";

    }

    $sql_query .= "GROUP BY Talent.id ";
    $sql_query .= "ORDER BY Talent.id DESC ";

    $this->recursive = $recursive;
    $this->virtualFields['fullname'] = 'CONCAT(Talent.firstname, " ", Talent.lastname)';
    $results = $this->query($sql_query);
    return count($results);
}
```

the value on `$this->paginateQuery;` is the same query as [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8560/1/0)

and i also need to alter the `$conditions` a bit since it comes as an array so i need to somehow concat the array to some acceptable where condition.

next in my controller, i call something like

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'Talent' => array(
        'limit' => 1,
        'conditions' => array(
            'TalentCategory = ' => 3,
            'TalentMedia.is_suspended !=' => 1,
            'TalentMedia.is_cover     !=' => 1,
            'TalentMedia.is_avatar    = ' => 1,
            //and any other conditions related to the joined table
        )
    )
);
$this->set('talents', $this->Paginator->paginate('Talent'));
```